# How is it possible to export subfolder in git repo to separate repo

Tags: git, export, history, directory

We have repo "misc" that had a few files and folders, but during time one folder become some mature that it is reasonable to move it out of "misc" to own repo.

Is there a way to extract to target/new repo folder from source repository (with all history) ?

Comment: You can clone the repo and the filter the unwanted changes out of the history of the repo. But really, you should just start fresh with a copy of the folder unless you really, *really* need the history.

Comment: copy without history is always simple BUT last approach. Git is powerful i believe that there is a solution.

Comment: see also http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples